# Wait for WPF app to load after starting with Process.Start()

Tags: wpf, process

I have a WinForms app that starts a wpf process running using `Process.Start`.  I would like to know when the WPF process is finished loading and I can access the `process.MainWindowHandle` property (its 0 before its completly loaded).

I tried polling but the handle is always 0.  However, if I debug and wait (after `Process.Start`) for the WPF app to load - I then will get the correct handle.

Does not work:

```
int maxCount=100000;
int count=0;
do
{
    wpfProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
    _hWnd = net4ReconProcess.MainWindowHandle;
    count++;
} while (_hWnd.ToInt32() == 0 || count > maxCount);
```

Comment: What is net4ReconProcess in the above code by the way?

Answer (score 6):

Add `process.Refresh();` to the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using a while loop for `WaitForInputIdle` is a non-sense because this call blocks the current thread until the other process has finished its initialization. After that, it always returns immediately. Please read the post [*WaitForInputIdle should really be called WaitForProcessStartupComplete – The Old New Thing*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100325-00/?p=14493/)

As raymond says it, it should really be called `WaitForProcessStartupComplete`.

You should use this code:

```
if (!wpfProcess.WaitForInputIdle(10000)) // 10 s timout
  throw new ApplicationException("Process takes too much time to start");
_hWnd = net4ReconProcess.MainWindowHandle;
```