# Why doesn't Process.WaitForInputIdle() work?

Tags: wpf, process

I am using Windows Automation to test my UI and am opening and closing processes.  I want to have a valid WindowHandle, but Process.WaitForInputIdle() doesn't wait long enough.  I have a work around, but don't understand why WaitForInputIdle() doesn't work.

Below is a small code snip:

```
Process = new Process
              {
                 StartInfo =
                 {
                     WorkingDirectory = directory,
                     FileName = EXECUTABLE_FILE_NAME
                 }
              };

Process.Start();

//Process.WaitForInputIdle() doesn't work, 
//so will use a while loop until MainWindowHandle isn't IntPtr.Zero anymore,
//or until 10 seconds have elapsed

int count = 0;

while (Process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero && count<100)
{
    count++;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}

AppElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(Process.MainWindowHandle);
```

Comment: Seems similar to the question asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247125/wait-for-wpf-app-to-load-after-starting-with-process-start). You might need to call Process.Refresh() at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Chaser324 in his comment, the answer to my question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247125/wait-for-wpf-app-to-load-after-starting-with-process-start).

I basically need to add a call to Process.Refresh() inside of my 'while' loop.